# NSwag openapi2cscontroller: handle controller return type for errors

Tags: c#, .net, nswag

Is there a way to tell NSwag to generate controllers using `Task<ActionResult>` as method output instead of `Task<MyDTO>`?

This is how my swagger looks like

```
paths:
  '/Products/{id}':
    get:
      tags:
        - Products
      operationId: getProductById
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
          content: 
            application/json:
              schema: 
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ProductResponseDto'
        '404':
          description: Entity not found
          content: 
            application/json:
              schema: 
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ErrorDto'
```

The generated interface looks like

```
    /// <returns>Success</returns>

    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ProductResponseDto> GetProductByIdAsync(string id);
```

and it does not allow to return the ErrorDto in case of error.
I know it is possible to throw an exception and add a middleware to handle it, but I want to find a solution that does not involve throwing exceptions.

This is how the target is defined in the csproj

```
<Target Name="GenerateControllers" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(Reference)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)References" />
    <Exec Command="$(NSwagExe_Net80) openapi2cscontroller /input:./product_openapi.yaml /classname:Products /namespace:AspNetCore.Examples.ProductService.Controllers /output:obj/ProductsController.cs /ControllerBaseClass:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase" />
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="obj/ProductsController.cs"
                 Exclude="@(Compile)" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```